# Ui is visible locally but not remotely in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is WEIRD!!
When developing locally I get the desired list of buttons when I click on the icon and when I test the website (not locally ofc) I get no buttons (invisible) but they are clickable so when I click on them I get the desired output as locally!!!
Any idea why this is happening please?!

Comment: without code, nobody can help you regarding the problem you are facing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.